# How to fix duplicate values while writing json in python

Tags: python, json

I have two files, after reading both files I am writing it to a json file in python. Problem is in the final json file I am getting duplicate json object (last json object appended).

I am able to read files and generate json file.

```
import json

data2 = {}
data1 = []
i = 1

with open('abc3') as json_file:
    f=open("abc2", "r")
    data = json.load(json_file)
    lines =f.readlines()
    for p,x in zip(data['Url'],lines):
        print(p['Urls'])
        print(x)
        print(i)
        print('')
        data2['videoId'] = i
        data2['videoUrl'] = p['Urls']
        data2['videName'] = x
        i = i + 1   
        data1.extend(data2)



with open('data1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data1, outfile)
```

Comment: classic mistake: create `data2 = {}` in the loop else same reference is shared

Comment: then `data1.extend(data2)`: you probably mean `data1.append(data2)` or you just add the keys to the list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks.. fixed.. I am new to python..it's append there ..

Answer (score 1):

reusing the same reference of `data2` is the main issue. Create a dictionary at each iteration.

And if you do `data1.extend(data2)`, `extend` iterates on the *keys* of the dictionary, when you want to create a list of dictionaries.

Quickfix:

```
for p,x in zip(data['Url'],lines):
    print(p['Urls'])
    print(x)
    print(i)
    print('')
    data2 = {}
    data2['videoId'] = i
    data2['videoUrl'] = p['Urls']
    data2['videName'] = x
    i = i + 1   
    data1.append(data2)
```

but a list comprehension would be clearer and more pythonic (note: don't read the lines, use `f` directly, it will avoid a useless file read):

```
data1 = [{"videoId":i,"videoUrl":p['Urls'],'videoName':x.rstrip()}
          for i,(p,x) in enumerate(zip(data['Url'],f),1)]
```

this creates a dictionary per iteration. `i` side-effect is replaced by the use of `enumerate` (starting at 1). Note the `rstrip()` operation needed to remove the end of line character when reading a file line by line.

To sum it up, here's how I'd rewrite the full code:

```
import json

with open('abc3') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

with open("abc2") as f:
    data1 = [{"videoId":i,"videoUrl":p['Urls'],'videoName':x.rstrip()}
              for i,(p,x) in enumerate(zip(data['Url'],f),1)]

with open('data1.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data1, outfile)
```